# How to store variable in crystal report formula?

Tags: crystal-reports

how to declare variables in crystal report ? coz i want to sum the total in sub-report and the total in the main-report to get the GRAND TOTAL of the report..i got a screenshot for my report...

[image]

i want to sum that `1000` which is the TOTAL in sub-report and that `808` total in the main report..how to do that in crystal report ? tnx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a formula in your sub-report that looks similar to the following:

```
shared numbervar a := sum({yourfield});
```

Place that somewhere on the canvas of your sub.
Then another in your main report that looks like this:

```
shared numbervar a;
```

Comment: it work mate..and my sub-report `shared Numbervar myAllo := SUM({SP_Project;1.alloted});
myAllo;`..and in the main report i make a formula to get the grand total `shared Numbervar myTotal;`
`SUM({@byAppro},{@byOfficeCode}) + myTotal;` and it works i got the total..but when i make another formula and i use the same shared variable again `shared Numbervar myTotal;` and now it didn't work..why is that ? is it ? it can only be use once ?

Comment: by your description above I am not sure how it is working correctly. Your sub is declaring MyAllo as a shared variable but I don't see that declaration in your main report. shared Numbervar myTotal; should result in myTotal = 0. So I may be missing something . To answer your question thgouh, yes it can be used more than once as long as it is placed in or after the section the subreport is located in the main report.

Comment: sorry it just a typo.. its `shared Numbervar myAllo` not `shared Numbervar myTotal`..why is that ?